# Iterate a two dimensional array1, change items at positions listed in array2

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, function, multidimensional-array

I have two dimensional array and another array of one dimension. I'd like to iterate over the 2d array, searching for values listed the one dimensional array.

If the value is found, change that value to 0 and change all others to 1.

```
array2d = [
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4],
  [5, 6],
  [7, 8],
];

array1 = [1, 8]

//desired output:
array2d = [
  [0, 1],
  [1, 1],
  [1, 1],
  [1, 0], 
]
```

so far, I can't find any combinations of array.filter(), array.map(), or array.reduce() that work correctly and remain concise. do I have to resort to a nested loop?

Comment: What do you mean by "concise"? You can map and then map again.

Comment: Could you provide what you _did_ try? What about it didn't work correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with nested maps

```js
const array2d = [
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4],
  [5, 6],
  [7, 8],
]

const array1 = [1, 8]

const output = array2d.map(sub => sub.map(el => array1.includes(el) ? 0 : 1))
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple nested `forEach` with `includes` would do the trick:

```js
array2d = [
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4],
  [5, 6],
  [7, 8],
];

array1 = [1, 8];

array2d.forEach((arr, i) => {
  arr.forEach((el, j) => {
    array2d[i][j] = array1.includes(el) ? 0 : 1;
  });
});

//works as a on-liner too:
//array2d.forEach((arr, i) => arr.forEach((el, j) => array2d[i][j] = array1.includes(el) ? 0 : 1));

console.log(array2d);
```

One advantage of this solution is if you want to keep the references to your arrays variables (doesn't create new arrays)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I may end up reverting back to this as the better option & will post as best answer if so :-)

Comment: @WilliamGreer There's no real better option, it depends on what you do with it. This answer is slighly longer than using `map` but as stated, no new array is created and it works on the original array. Use `map` if you want to preserve original array, use this one if you want to keep var references (you can even mix the 2)